# L'Hopital's Rule (Extended Thm Proof)

Tags: calculus

I have found an excellent proof of [L'Hôpital's Rule](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/sadun/F11/408N/L'Hopital.pdf). However, there is one problem I have with it which I was wanting some other people's opinions on. This problem deals with the application of the baby or macho thms to deduce the extended thm. I have wrote the part I am confused with below and would greatly appreciate any help with this.

For the extended thm this site states the following:

$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(1/g)'}{(1/f)'}$ by baby or macho L'Hôpital's Rule. However, it does not acknowledge the fact that $\lim_{x\to a} (1/f)'\neq 0$ which I believe needs to be satisfied in order to use the lemma from the baby and macho versions. Therefore, I would say that $f'(a)\neq 0$ in order for the proof to be valid. Am I incorrect with my assumption or is this point a singularity for the proof?

Comment: There is nothing in that paper I can see that cannot be found in a first level real analysis course, except a willingness to use results without bothering to check if they actually apply, of which you have noticed but one of multiple intstances (another: it states that because $L = \lim \frac{1/g}{1/f}$, it must be that $L = \lim \frac{(1/g)'}{(1/f)'}$ without bothering to check that the latter limit exists, as required by the "macho theorem").

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Sometimes I think that I must be missing something. This just reassures it.

Comment: I misinterpreted the situation here. I thought this was something someone else wrote and you are asking how important and reliable it was. So my answer was harsher than it should have been for critiquing your own writing. The issues I mentioned are real, but I did not mean to dissuade you from developing your ideas. You can examine and fix the limit issues, and for your own satisfaction, i suggest you do so. It would be good practice.

Comment: I did not write it lol. Thank you for your considering my feelings though ; )

Comment: Well, I guess I am still guilty of misinterpretation!